# sed - Remove parts of certain strings across multiple files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

From the tutorial [here](https://rushi.wordpress.com/2008/08/05/find-replace-across-multiple-files-in-linux/), I learned to find and replace text across multiple files from the Linux command line. For example,

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

finds all instances of 'foo' in files that end with '.php' and replaces such instances with 'bar'.

Now suppose I have multiple, redundant occurrences of something like `assert something.makeAssertion` that I want to replace with just `something.makeAssertion`. Given that `something` can vary, how do I adapt the script for this? I tried some things with `$` to capture `something` as a variable (?) but haven't figured it out.

Comment: It's always best to show both the input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superficially, you could use:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec \
    sed -i.bak -e 's/assert\(.*\.makeAssertion\)/\1/g' {} +
```

The regex drops the `assert` when there's a `.makeAssertion` later on the line.  The `find … -exec` runs the `sed` on the files it finds.  The `+` indicates 'group a convenient number of files into a single command line', rather like `xargs` but without some complications.  An alternative using GNU `find` and `xargs` would be:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 |
    xargs -0 sed -i.bak -e 's/assert\(.*\.makeAssertion\)/\1/g'
```

Both these avoid problems with spaces or newlines in file names.